# Bash - ssh'ing to hosts in associative array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, ssh

I am writing a script that stores client connection data such as session ID, server, and port in an associative array.  I need to ssh onto these hosts, and run an lsof command to find what process is using this port.

```
declare -A HOSTMAP
HOSTMAP[session]=$session_ids
HOSTMAP[cname]=$cnames
HOSTMAP[port]=$ports
```

When printed, data in the array is displayed as so (host names and ports have been changed to protect the innocent)

```
for g in "${!HOSTMAP[@]}"
do
   printf "[%s]=%s\n" "$g" "${HOSTMAP[$g]}"
done
```

```
[cname]=hostname1
hostname2
hostname3
hostname4
hostname5
hostname6
hostname7
hostname8
[session]=44
5
3
9
14
71
65
47
[port]=11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
66666
77777
88888
```

I would like to do an operation akin to the following:

```
for session in $session_id
    do
    echo "Discovering application mapped to session ${session} on ${cname}:${port}"
    ssh -tq ${cname} "lsof -Tcp | grep ${port}"
done
```

Many thanks in advance for advising on an elegant solution

Comment: FYI, you can specify the port number in an argument to `lsof`: `lsof -i :$port`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` doesn't allow nesting of arrays. Here, I would just use separate indexed arrays. However, since your session appears to be an integers, and indexed arrays are sparse, you can use the session id as the index for the cnames and the ports.

```
cnames=([44]=hostname1 [5]=hostname2 [3]=hostname3)
ports=([44]=1111 [5]=2222 [3]=3333)

for session in "${!cnames[@]}"; do
  cname=${cnames[$session]}
  port=${ports[$session]}
  echo "Discovering application mapped to session ${session} on ${cname}:${port}"
  ssh -tq ${cname} "lsof -Tcp | grep ${port}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It's close to the answer I'm looing for.  However the script will be collecting this data from multiple servers, so hostnames, sessions, and ports will always vary.  I would need to implement this without hard coding the session indexes.

Comment: Where does the session index come from? You don't have to hard code them like I showed. For example, `session=$(get_new_session_id); cnames+=([$session]=newhost); ports+=([$session]=65432)`. You can also remove a given session `x` with `unset "cnames[$x]" "ports[$x]"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the output of `ssh` to a variable

```
result=$(ssh -tq ${cname} "lsof -Tcp | grep ${port}")
```

Then you can extract the data you want from `$result`.